# e.Row.RowIndex throwing Argument out of Range Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, sqldatasource

This doesn't make sense to me: if I run this code:

```
protected void viewStoryTime_OnRowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        var obj = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem)["ActivityDate"];
        if (DateTime.Parse(obj.ToString()) < DateTime.Now.StartOfWeek(DayOfWeek.Monday))
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.Row.RowIndex);
        }
    }
}
```

My output is:

```
4
```

Now if I try to use this to clear a cell:

```
protected void viewStoryTime_OnRowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        var obj = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem)["ActivityDate"];
        if (DateTime.Parse(obj.ToString()) < DateTime.Now.StartOfWeek(DayOfWeek.Monday))
        {
            viewStoryTime.Rows[e.Row.RowIndex].Cells[3].Controls.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

I get:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additionally, I get this exception if I manually input 4:

```
viewStoryTime.Rows[e.Row.RowIndex].Cells[3].Controls.Clear();
```

If I input 3 however it removes the control from the column directly before the one that it should:

[image]

Why am I getting this exception and what can I do about it?

Comment: What happens if you just do this?  : 

`e.Row.Cells[3].Controls.Clear();`

Comment: It's an argument exception, not an index out of range exception.  What is the value of `viewStoryTime.Rows[e.Row.RowIndex].Cells[3]` and `viewStoryTime.Rows[e.Row.RowIndex].Cells[3].Controls`?  Can you provide the stack trace?

Comment: Also, I don't see where you're "manually inputting 4".

Comment: And are you sure you have at least 4 Cells in your row?  (otherwise, Cells[3] will be the thing that's generating ArgumentOutOfRangeException)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on everything you've tried, the only way you're getting this exception is for `e.Row.RowIndex` to be out of range:

```
viewStoryTime.Rows[e.Row.RowIndex]...
```

However, it's unclear to me why you don't simply do this:

```
e.Row.Cells[3].Controls.Clear();
```

You could have issues accessing the rows on `viewStoryTime` depending on where the page is in the event life cycle.